# error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 27,Token in error = int ]

Tags: c#

I am creating a .sdf file programatically, and a table, it is working fine, but when try to make an insert i get an error,
can anyone please tell me why I am getting this error
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 27,Token in error = int ]
Here is my code

```
private void createDbAndInsert()
    {
        String PersonalFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        string connStr = "Data Source = " + PersonalFolder + "\\FooDatabase.sdf; Password = SomePassword";

        if (!File.Exists(PersonalFolder + "\\FooDatabase.sdf"))
        {
            SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connStr);
            engine.CreateDatabase();

            SqlCeConnection conn = null;
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlCeConnection(connStr);
                conn.Open();

                SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE FooTable(col1 int, col2 ntext)";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error has occured.." + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        insertDataToTable();
    }

    private void insertDataToTable()
    {
        String PersonalFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        string connStr = "Data Source = " + PersonalFolder + "\\FooDatabase.sdf; Password = SomePassword";

        SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = " + PersonalFolder + "\\FooDatabase.sdf; Password = SomePassword");
        con.Open();

        SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO FooTable(col1 int, col2 ntext) values(@col1, @col2)", con);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", 1);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col2", "some text here");

        try
        {
            int affectedRows = cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (affectedRows > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("OK");

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not OK");
            }
        }
        catch (SqlCeException ex)
        {
            // do something here.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put the column datatype for insert query

Just try this code instead of your insert query

```
 SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO FooTable(col1 , col2 ) values(@col1, @col2)", con);
```

and you don't need this

```
int affectedRows = cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Just write this below line instead of above line

```
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Because you did't return any values from your insert query. So it'a may be threw the conversion error

Cheer's ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**  You are providing column `datatypes` while inserting items into table using `INSERT INTO` statement as below:

```
                            |          |
                            |          |
                            >          >
"INSERT INTO FooTable(col1 int, col2 ntext) values(@col1, @col2)"
```

**Solution :** You should not provide the Columns types  while inserting items into table

Replace This:

```
SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO FooTable(col1 int, col2 ntext) values(@col1, @col2)", con);
```

With This:

```
SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO FooTable(col1, col2) values(@col1, @col2)", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting datatype also.Thats why it creating error.try this insert query.

```
SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO FooTable(col1, col2) values(@col1, @col2)", con);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", 1);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", "some text here");
```